# Why is my arduino digital signal flickering on my oscilloscope display?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a very simple arduino program:

```
void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(8, LOW);
digitalWrite(9, LOW);
digitalWrite(10, LOW);
digitalWrite(11, LOW);
digitalWrite(12, LOW);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(9, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(8, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(10);
}
```

For some reason when I hook up my oscilloscope probe, the signals I am getting are flickering like the image below:

[image]

My code shows that the signal should go high then back down to low only 1 time, but as you can see in the picture the signal is going high 2 times instead of 1. Anybody have any idea why this is the case?

I also tried using the analogWrite (32kHz) function instead of writing each pin high / low and when I hooked it up to my probes it didn't have the same flicker effect even though the PWM frequency was higher then it was just using the digitalWrite / delayMicroseconds function in my code. This tells me that my scope is not the problem and it is indeed a problem with the arduino. Anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: Looks like trace persistence in the scope to me.

Comment: @Bryan I don't think this is the case because my scope is rated for 100MHz, and when I tried measuring the same thing with a 32kHz signal instead of the 20kHz signal on the picture above it had no flickering effect

Comment: maybe the scope triggering is not set correctly

Comment: Try with a synchro signal by adding a short pulse on another output ...

Comment: do not use: pinMode() & digitalWrite(), download the datasheet of the ATMEL328P, look for the port, data direction, pull up resistor registers, using C/C++ "bitfields unions" you can access pins much faster as wel check/toggle/change 2 more more pins at the same time, create a "volatile bitfield union" and assign the reference/address of the port register via &. much much faster and time saving then using the Arduino "language". look for online examples how to SET/TOGGLE/INV bits via a C/C++ "static inline" function.

Answer (score 1):

The scope is showing multiple captures for some reason.

If you use single capture it will stop after only only one trigger.

The waveform may looks wrong compared to what you expect, but you must not expect a clean timing, because your software generated pulses have timing jitter, and in comparison, the hardware generated PWM has very stable timing.

So it is the scope showing multiple runs of unstable signal, and the multiple runs are not identical. So you decide if it is the scope setting problem if it shows multiple runs, or Arduino not outputing stable signals.